# Unity3D. How to construct components programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, constructor, unity-components

I'm new to unity and am having a bit of trouble getting my head around the architecture.

Lets say I have a C# script component called 'component A'.
I'd like component A to have an array of 100 other components of type 'component B'.
How do I construct the 'component B's programmatically with certain values?

Note that 'component B' is derived from 'MonoBehaviour' as it needs to be able to call 'StartCoroutine'

I'm aware that in unity you do not use constructors as you normally would in OO.

Comment: You would use [GameObject.AddComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) to add components dynamically.  You can then use the return value to set the properties of component B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note that 'component B' is derived from 'MonoBehaviour' as it needs to
>   be able to call 'StartCoroutine'
>
> I'm aware that in unity you do not use constructors as you normally
>   would in OO.

That's true. A possibility is to istantiate components at runtime and provide a method to initialize them ( if initialization requires arguments, otherwise all initialization can be done inside `Start` or `Awake` methods ).

> How do I construct the 'component B's programmatically with certain
>   values?

Here's a possible way:

```
public class BComponent : MonoBehavior
{
  int id;
  public void Init(int i)
  {
    id = i;
  }
}
}
public class AComponent : MonoBehavior
{
  private BComponent[] bs;

  void Start()
  {
    bs = new BComponent[100];
    for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
      bs[i] = gameObject.AddComponent<BComponent>().Init(i);
    }
   }
}
```

Note that in the example above all components will be attached to the same GameObject, this might be not what you want. Eventually try to give more details.

Comment: Actually after trying it, I dont think u can just call 'AddComponent' like that.. I think you have to say gameObject.AddComponent<>()

Comment: Is there a way to AddComponents in the same manner as RequireComponent which can operate outside run-time?

Comment: yes, AddComponent can be called from editor scripts too.

Comment: But here in case `Init()` returns a `void`.